# How can i draw tiles on canvas using p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to make an html5 game using p5.js and first thing I tried to implement is to draw a tilemap but my code does not work.

I used nested loop to draw the tiles but I need something faster, I found an
other algorithm that uses one dimensional array to draw tiles I tried that algo but it does not work and I dont know why?

```
let tileset;
let map = [
    0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1
];

function preload() {
    tileset = loadImage("./tileset.png");
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    drawTiles(map, 3, 11);
}

function drawTiles(map, cols, tilesize) {
    for (let i = map.length - 1; i > -1; --i) {
        let value = map[i];
        // source x , y
        let sx = (value % cols) * tilesize;
        let sy = Math.floor(value / cols) * tilesize;
        // distenation x , y
        let dx = (i % cols) * tilesize;
        let dy = Math.floor(i / cols) * tilesize;
        // render image
        image(tileset, sx, sy, tilesize, tilesize, dx, dy, tilesize, tilesize);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I used nested loop to draw the tiles but i need something faster "* Why do you think, that a loop which iterates from 0 to 8 is faster than 2 nested loop where both loops iterate from 0 to 2? In both cases the inner loop is executed 9 times. So the time complexity is equal.

Comment: what if there is more than 9 grids

Comment: What do you mean? The inner loop is executed in both cases the same number if times (independent on the size of the grid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've swapped source and destination. In [`image`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/image) the first rectangular area (parameters 2 -5) define the destination in the window and the second rectangular area (parameters 6 - 9) define the source rectangle in image (`tileset`):

<s>`image(tileset, sx, sy, tilesize, tilesize, dx, dy, tilesize, tilesize);`</s>

```js
image(tileset, dx, dy, tilesize, tilesize, sx, sy, tilesize, tilesize);
```

Since the destination grid an and the source `tileset` have a different number of columns, the function `drawTiles`, needs 2 columns parameters (`d_cols`,  `c_cols`):

```js
function draw() {
    background(0);
    drawTiles(map, 3, 2, 11);
}
```

```js
function drawTiles(map, d_cols, s_cols, tilesize) {
    for (let i = map.length - 1; i > -1; --i) {
        let value = map[i];
        // source x , y
        let sx = (value % s_cols) * tilesize;
        let sy = Math.floor(value / s_cols) * tilesize;
        // distenation x , y
        let dx = (i % d_cols) * tilesize;
        let dy = Math.floor(i / d_cols) * tilesize;
        // render image
        image(tileset, dx, dy, tilesize, tilesize, sx, sy, tilesize, tilesize);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it's working but there is a problem , i have a tileset image contains 4 tiles each tile is 11x11 pixels , witch mean the first two tiles on the tileset image is 0,1 and second row in the tileset image is 2 , 3 , when i use 2 and 3 on map array it does not work .

Comment: Thanks for help :)